# DbDriver warning & error for trying connection PostgreSQL & onlyoffice

Tags: postgresql, debconf

I'm trying to connect my PostgreSQL database with the Onlyoffice System on my Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS system.

I use the instruction from https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/installation/docs-community-install-ubuntu.aspx

I just got to the step where I am supposed to set the password with the command:

```
echo onlyoffice-documentserver onlyoffice/db-pwd password <DB_PASSWORD> | debconf-set-selections
```

For <DB_PASSWORD> I used the one I created with

```
sudo -i -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'password';"
```

After sending the "echo" command, I get the following message in the console:

```
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
error: Cannot find a question for onlyoffice/db-pwd
debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": could not write /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat-new: Permission denied
```

I tried using chmod to change the permissions to 777, but that didn't solve my problem either. Unfortunately, I have not found any solutions to my situation. I have followed these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I found the problem...

```
echo onlyoffice-documentserver onlyoffice/db-pwd password <DB_PASSWORD> | debconf-set-selections
```

must change to

```
echo onlyoffice-documentserver onlyoffice/db-pwd password <DB_PASSWORD> | **sudo** debconf-set-selections
```